# Mongo Aggregate: Group and Sort Token error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm struggling with something which is most likely very stupid on my behalf.

I have a data set in a mongo collection and I wanted to get all the sum of documents grouped by year and month (which I can do fine). However I then want to have those results ordered by year and month.

Here is my query for getting the results with just the sum:

```
db.xxxx.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: { year:
                    { $year: "$createdDate" },
                      month: { $month: "$createdDate" }
               },
        total_users: { $sum: 1 }
    },
}
])
```

Which results in this:

```
[
  { _id: { year: 2021, month: 12 }, total_users: 191 },
  { _id: { year: 2021, month: 6 }, total_users: 51 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 3 }, total_users: 165 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 8 }, total_users: 61 },
  { _id: { year: 2021, month: 8 }, total_users: 182 },
  { _id: { year: 2021, month: 11 }, total_users: 81 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 4 }, total_users: 155 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 7 }, total_users: 10 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 5 }, total_users: 31 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 9 }, total_users: 23 },
  { _id: { year: 2021, month: 7 }, total_users: 48 },
  { _id: { year: 2021, month: 10 }, total_users: 75 },
  { _id: { year: 2021, month: 5 }, total_users: 11 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 2 }, total_users: 300 },
  { _id: { year: 2021, month: 9 }, total_users: 131 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 1 }, total_users: 172 },
  { _id: { year: 2022, month: 6 }, total_users: 65 }
]
```

Now once I try and sort by month and year I get a token error:

```
db.xxxx.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: { year:
                    { $year: "$createdDate" },
                      month: { $month: "$createdDate" }
               },
        total_users: { $sum: 1 }
    },
    {$sort: {year:1}}, 
    {$sort: {month:1}}
}
])
```

Resulting error:

```
Uncaught:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:4)

   8 |         total_users: { $sum: 1 }
   9 |     },
> 10 |     {$sort: {year:1}},
     |     ^
  11 |

Atlas [primary] collection>     {$sort: {month:1}}
1
Atlas [primary] collection> }
Uncaught:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)

> 1 | }
    | ^
  2 |
```

Any help would be very welcome!!

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's the query now the suggested sort query:

```
db.xxx.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: { year:
                    { $year: "$createdDate" },
                      month: { $month: "$createdDate" }
               },
        total_users: { $sum: 1 }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
          "_id.year": 1,
          "_id.month": 1
        }
      }
}
])
```

Note I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use:

```
{$sort: {"_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1}}
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jNBH-RFRh2A)

**EDIT**:
You have misplayed the `}`. The `$group` is missing one at the end and the `$sort` have extra one. It should be:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: {year: {$year: "$createdDate"}, month: {$month: "$createdDate"}},
      total_users: {$sum: 1}
    }
  },
  {$sort: {"_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1}}
])
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast response! I'm still getting the token error though. I assume its now just how I'm structuring the query? I've made sure I've the correct backets

EDIT...updating the question body as I can't paste code here...

Comment: Yes, you have misplayed the `}`. The `$group` is missing one at the end and the `$sort` have extra one

Comment: Well I feel terribly dumb now :-D Thanks a million for the spot!

Comment: Happens to us all :)

Comment: haha thanks again! And over the moon with the fast response. That would have killed me going to bed! Thanks and take care \m/